# Array's elements compare

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

If there is an array, How to compare each element with all the elements before it in the index ?

I used two of for loops but it seems not working .

for example :

arr = [10, 20, 5, 4, 17, .... etc]
I want to compare and check if 20 > 10
, also compare 5  to       20, 10
, also compare 4  to    5, 20, 10
, also compare 17 to 4, 5, 20, 10
and so on .....

any help please ?

I expect a result of array elements comparison which contain 2 for loops , one for the main array looping and one for element loop to start of the array .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If yo uwant to have two loops and need to check each combination you can do it as below:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

arr = array.from(10, 20, 5, 4, 17, 20)

f_comp(p_val1, p_val2) =>
    s = ""

    if (p_val1 > p_val2)
        s := str.tostring(p_val1) + " is greater than " + str.tostring(p_val2)
    else if (p_val1 < p_val2)
        s := str.tostring(p_val1) + " is less than " + str.tostring(p_val2)
    else
        s := str.tostring(p_val1) + " is equal to " + str.tostring(p_val2)

f_method1(p_arr) =>
    len = array.size(p_arr)
    s = "Method 1\n"
    s := s + "Array: " + str.tostring(p_arr) + "\n"

    if (len > 1)
        for i = 1 to len - 1
            for k = 0 to i - 1
                val1 = array.get(p_arr, i)
                val2 = array.get(p_arr, k)
                s_comp = f_comp(val1, val2)
                s := s + "Comparing " + str.tostring(val1) + " with " + str.tostring(val2) + ": " + s_comp + "\n"
    s

if (barstate.islast)
    s1 = f_method1(arr)
    label.new(bar_index, high, s1, yloc=yloc.abovebar, textcolor=color.white)
```

[image]

However, if you need to check if the current element is greater than all the previous elements, this is an inefficient solution. You can do this with much better performance by [dynamic programming](https://www.spiceworks.com/tech/devops/articles/what-is-dynamic-programming/#:%7E:text=Dynamic%20programming%20is%20defined%20as,minimum%20range%20of%20the%20algorithmic). You just need one for loop and basically you need to save the maximum number up to that point (in your loop) in a variable and compare the current element with that variable.

Comment: Words fail to describe my thanks and gratitude to you and your valuable time and effort.